# Android OpenCV Tutorial 3 Error Saving Image

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I loaded up the OpenCV library and demos into Eclipse and was able to run them without issues. I have since taken the tutorial 3 code (capture image, etc.) and modified it slightly to instead save an image with the same name every time in a specific location, where after I proceed to run some other OpenCV functions on this. This was working until a few days ago when I accidentally deleted the folder where this image was stored on my phone. My code checked to make sure the folder existed and if not then it created it before the photo was to be taken. Now though, the image never saves and there is no specific error in the logcat as to why. I will get a logcat posted in a few hours as I don't currently have my laptop with me.  If anyone has any idea why this would occur please let me know. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you created the folder with some user or access permissions that do not allow your Android application to write on that folder. You need to research more about Android file system permissions...

Also make sure your Android application is allowed to read/write to the filesystem:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

You will find dozens of posts here on SO and elsewhere addressing these issues.